# Any working android app using phonegap and couchdb together?

Tags: cordova, couchdb

I am looking for examples of an android app using phonegap for accessing native APIs and couchdb for persistence.

Answer (score 2):

here's some more discussion on this, but haven't seen yet anything finalized:

[link](https://groups.google.com/group/mobile-couchbase/browse_thread/thread/f4e9bc30e1dd3818)

another example of a phoneGap plugin to upload attachments to couchDB:

[link](http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2011/03/14/phonegap-couchdb-attachment-plugin/)

Comment: yes, as I wrote above nothing is finalized - I only ever saw ONE PhoneGap/CouchDB (local!), that was created by CouchBase for their own conference, so I know it's possible but no source code available. If this still answers your question, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as Answer for the other members. Thanks!